# Filtering array based on multiple key where key are dynamic in nature

Tags: javascript, filter, vue.js

I am trying to filter array on key where keys are dynamic in nature. The checkbox will add another key to array.
There are two type of ride [A,B], when user select A, only ride of type A get displayed and when user select B, only ride of type B get rendered, if both are selected, all rides are get rendered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <div id="filters">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="A" v-model="rideFilter"> Ride Type A 
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="B" v-model="fileFilter"> Ride Type B 
    </div>
    <div id="rides">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="ride in rideAfterFilter">
                {{ride.src}} - {{ride.dest}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        rides: [
            {src:'A',dest:'G',type:'A'},
            {src:'B',dest:'H',type:'B'},
            {src:'C',dest:'A',type:'A'},
            {src:'D',dest:'B',type:'B'},
            {src:'E',dest:'E',type:'C'},
            {src:'F',dest:'D',type:'D'},
        ],
        rideFilter:[]
    },
    computed:{
        rideAfterFilter:function (){
            this.rides.filter(function(ride){
                //here 
            });
        }
    }

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uhm, what have you tried?

Comment: no idea. just stucked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rideAfterFilter: function() {
  return this.rides.filter((ride) => {
    return this.rideFilter.includes(ride.type)
  });
}
```

By using [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) we can check if the `ride` that is currently being filtered has a `type` included in the `rideFilter` array.

`.filter()` itself needs a Boolean, and `.includes()` provides it.

And the last thing: I used fat arrow syntax in the `.filter()` callback because we have to access `this` as the current Vue instance.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/p8Lsh88L/1/

---

Edit: after reading on a bit about `this` in `.filter()` I found that you can provide it as the second argument, so if you don't want to use the fat arrow syntax you can use it like this:

```
rideAfterFilter: function() {
  return this.rides.filter(function(ride)  {
    return this.rideFilter.includes(ride.type)
  }, this);
}
```

Alternative JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/h6su1won/